# Can I have two castings of minor illusion active at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, cantrips

I had made a new half-elf sorcerer who will soon be a rogue multi-class. His spells are based off of what a rogue would choose them to be, such as *fog cloud*, *mage hand*, and *minor illusion*. In addition, I chose *prestidigitation* in the hopes of combining with *minor illusion*, using one for sound and one for an image.

Yet it was never clear to me if I could just use *minor illusion* twice, as it is a cantrip. This will free up a cantrip spot for a more offensive spell, seeing as all of my other spells are more ability than offense. We are playing D&D 5E.

**Can I have two castings of minor illusion active at the same time?**

Comment: Are you trying to use the spell twice on the same turn, or simply have its effects active for multiple castings of it whose durations overlap?

Comment: Having its effects active during the same time

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## One character can't have more than one casting of *minor illusion* active at a time.

From the description of the [*minor illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spell:

> You create a sound or an image of an object within range that lasts for the duration. **The illusion also ends** if you dismiss it as an action **or cast this spell again.**

Let's say that a character casts *minor illusion* once (let's say, to create a visual illusion of a rock). He then wants to cast the spell again (e.g. to create the sound of a lion's roar). However, as soon as he casts *minor illusion* the second time, the first illusion ends and goes away.

In order to have multiple illusions active at once, you'd need to use a different spell, or have someone else cast *minor illusion* the second time. Since it is a cantrip, it could be pretty overpowered to let one character just create an unlimited number of illusions that were all active at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

## Not at the same time, but quickly after

The rules state that if you cast minor illusion again then one illusion replaces the other. That said it only takes a 6 second round to cast so you could for instance create the noise of a rock fall,then quickly cast again to show a stationary pile of rocks blocking a passage. No good if you are directly observed but good enough if enemies aren't in line of sight.